# Generate mpeg-dash live content from transport stream UDP input using ffmpeg/mp4box

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, mp4box

I'm receiving mpeg-2 transport stream UDP input. I want to serve this content using an HTTP server.

I know that mp4box can be used to grab the udp and dump it in a file.

```
mp4box -grab-ts udp://ip:port dump.ts
```

mp4box can generate mpeg-dash content using `-dash` argument

Is it possible to combine the `-grab-ts` argument with `-dash-live` and generate live dash content?